# Prevent getting whole context value in Json.NET Serializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am using Json.NET serializer to send data.

```
public string GetAllBuildingType()
  {
    IEnumerable<Model.BuildingType> getAll = CEEPMSContext.BuildingType_Repository.GetAll();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getAll);
   }
```

In Repository **GetAll** function

```
public IEnumerable<BuildingType> GetAll()
{
    return context.BuildingTypes.ToList();           
}
```

I want only **BuildingType** data but getting data of whole context in it.
How can i get only **BuildingType** data?Is that i am missing something in Json.NET or its implemented in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

After many research on this problem i couldn't find out the reason why its taking data of whole conext :(
However i solved the problem by parsing the required table from the context.

```
BuildingType building = new BuildingType();
building.id = context.BuildingType.Id;
building.name = context.BuildingType.name;
.....

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(building);
```

This way its sending the correct data.